# Explode string with japanese character?

Tags: character-encoding, converters

$string = "あ,ｓ";
explode(",", $string);
this code its work, but when I change string = "あ、ｓ" "," to japanese character "、" its doesn't work.
How can I fix this problem. please help me! thanks so much!
note: $string Im get from database (ASCII)

Answer (score 0):

Use mb_split function for multibyte characters.

array mb_split ( string $pattern , string $string [, int $limit = -1 ] )

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php

Comment: yes thanks for answer I already use mb_split but not ok.
I resolved this problem I convert "、" (ascii) to utf8  with website http://kanjidict.stc.cx/recode.php and paste result to function explode